# Prevent default action

Tags: javascript, jsf, button, command, richfaces

This page open in **newwindow**.
  I have one text box and two button(h:commandbutton and a4j:commandButton).

I move(set) the cursor focus into textfield.

My problem is, i hit enter button from textfield, then **automattically called h:comandButton action and close the new window**. How to avoid this.

But, I need , when i hit enter button, move the cursor focus to **a4j:commandButton**

```
<f:view>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <script type="text/javascript">

            function a4jButtonClick()
            {
                alert("A4J Command Buton clicked...");
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <h:form id="sampleForm">
            <rich:panel id="samplePanel">

            <h:outputText value="User Name : "/>
            <h:inputText/>

            <h:commandButton value="Closing-CommandButton" 
                             onclick="javascript:window.close();return false;"/>

            <a4j:commandButton value="A4JCommandButton" onclick="a4jButtonClick()"/>                      

            </rich:panel>
        </h:form>
    </body>
</html>
</f:view>
```

If i hit enter button from textfiled, i want to call the script  alert("A4J Command Buton clicked...");

Help me.
Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add return false in onclick handler:

```
<h:commandButton value="HCommandButton" onclick="hButtonClick();return false;"/>
<a4j:commandButton value="A4JCommandButton" onclick="a4jButtonClick();return false;"/>
```

But then your form will not be submitted when you press buttons.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Now i update my question. I use return false. Eventhough the the window is closed.

Comment: of course is closed, window.close() called before return false :)

Comment: ok. First i use onclick"return false;javascript:window.close();".  But If manually i click "Closing-CommandButton", the new window is not closed.

Comment: you want to close window or not? or you want to prevent button action? if you want to prevent form submitting - return false at the end of onclick must help you.

Comment: If i click close button, then i need close window. Issue is, set the cursor point in text filed. Now hit the enter button in keyboard, that time window is automatically closed. No need to automatic close. Manually i click close button, then close winwow.

Comment: i think now u understand my problem

Comment: try to move buttons in another <h:form></h:form>

Comment: Thanks ultor. Its worked...Suppose Using single form is not possible??? Because i used so many componets using my page. The close button is lie in center of page. that time how to use different form

Comment: In this case, need to understand how the form is submitting and why was submitted on some action.

Answer (score 0):

When you hit Enter/Return on the keyboard the first button *in the markup* is activated.

So you need to change the order of your button in the markup to this:

```
<a4j:commandButton value="A4JCommandButton" onclick="a4jButtonClick()"/>
<h:commandButton value="Closing-CommandButton" onclick="javascript:window.close();return false;"/>
```

Bear in mind that *you can still style them* to be in the original order so the design doesn't change.